# Set parameters of an object using a variable in the reference visual basic

Tags: arrays, vba, object, reference

I would like to achieve the following in visual basic. Is it possible to be able to have the reference change with each iteration inside the for loop? I have an array of object names (as Strings) stored in "objectArray" that contains the names of objects with the property "valuePath". I would like to change the property of "valuePath" for each object from "objectArray" in one for loop. I do not want to statically call each of the objects manually. I can access the property of the object by calling "Me.objectName.valuePath" from inside the method where this code exists.

```
For item in objectArray
    Me.item.valuePath = "some value"
Next
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What is an "object name"  ?  Do you mean string representations of object-typed variables?  Might help to show a more-complete sample of your code.  What is Me here?  A custom class instance?

Comment: I expect he means 'variablename of object' when he says 'objectname'.

Comment: There can be different methods like `Sheet` object in excel, ***First***, As you have stored only names in the array you can refer to those objects individually like `ObjectCollection(ObjectArray(index))` just like `Sheets(SheetNamesArray(Index))` or `Sheets("Sheets1")`, ***Second***, Make and array or collection of the objects and then `for each item in the array or collection` will work like `item.property`  ... As `objectArray` is a string array, `For item in objectArray` is not referring to individual Object but individual String in the array.

Comment: Thank you - I will try and make an array of objects instead of an array of Strings with the object names and see how that goes. Will send an update after I try it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up saving an array of Objects instead of an array of Strings and that solved my problem. Thank you for your assistance!